# Get rid of MetaMask warning

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am using web3 with MetaMask. When injecting web3 I get the following warning:

```
MetaMask: We will stop injecting web3 in Q4 2020.
Please see this article for more information: https://medium.com/metamask/no-longer-injecting-web3-js-4a899ad6e59e
```

Is there a possibility to hide those warnings?